# How to choose seat with JAL when online check-in is not available?

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, seating, jal

I have a flight with one leg operated by Air France and the other one by JAL. Apparently, I cannot choose my seat from the Air France website and cannot check-in online on the JAL website. Is there any way for me to choose my seat?

Also, I will Premium Economy on JAL, are all seat of equivalent quality like in Business or is there bigger differences between seats like in Economy?

Comment: Did you try "Manage My Booking" on the JAL site?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes I get the same problem where I'm unable to perform this online; what I do -  I call directly to the airline (have your PNR/ticket number ready) and ask to have your seat assignment. It will be wise if you know the type of airplane before so you can get visualization about the layout).

Also, when you get your seat assignment over the phone - ask to have it recored in the PNR (this is obvious but I had a case where there was no indication for my seat).

For "Premium Economy on JAL" you will need to know the type of airplane and route; sometimes there's different layout for different plane/routes.